# In Java, is there some kind of Interface-like that enforces its implementing classes to have specific fields

Tags: java, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have learned that Java doesn't allow instance fields in an Interface, but I really want this feature.

I am learning to create my first game. My game has different kind of actors such as `Hero` (to be control by the player), `Boss`, `Canon`, etc...

No matter which kind they are, I want that every actors inherit from the base class `Model` which imparts some fields to its subclasses such as `position`, `width` and `height` so that every subclasses of `Model` can associate with `Controller` and `Renderer` as in MVC pattern.

```
public class Model {
    //position
    public float x;
    public float y;

    public float width;
    public float height;
}
```

Incidentally, I intended that `Hero` and `Boss` are entities that can die, so I want that they are instances of `Life` which is enforced to have, for example, `public float hitPoint;` as a field, in contrast, a `Cannon` is not a `Life` because it will be an immortal entity. Thus I tried:

```
public interface Life {
    public float hitPoint;
}
```

and expected that an instance of

```
public class Hero extends Model implements Life {...}
```

will intrinsically have the `hitPoint`. But then I learned that instance fields in an Interface are not allow in Java, and it don't support multiple inheritance as well.

**Is it possible to achieve the above mentioned design in Java.**

Comment: I believe you need Abstract class instead of an interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only constants can be declared in an interface.

anything you define in an interface is always `public static final` (except for the methods ofcourse as they are `public abstract`) if the `hitpoints` value will never change then  this design works for you.

A better solution would be this

```
public interface Life {
  //methods that implementation of this interface should implement
}

public abstract LifeForm extends Model implements Life {
  int hitPoints;
  //other LifeForm specific methods and instance variables
}

public Hero extends LifeForm {
  //Hero specific methods like save the damsel
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is 'no'. As you mention, Java doesn't support multiple inheritance -- there are some things you just can't do. However, one can almost always work around this limitation with clever application design. For example, why can't 'Life' extend 'Model'? Or perhaps you could just define accessors (e.g. getHitPoints()) in interfaces? If you really feel the need for an approximation of multiple inheritance, check out Aspect Oriented Programming extensions like [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj).

Answer (score 1):

Does it make sense to you to declare `Life` and `Model` as field members and change their initial values and state depending on each of the desired `Actor` implementation?
For example, set the `life`'s value to Infinity for the `Cannon` objects and to a finite value for other `Actors`. When you modify the `life`'s value, just be sure to check for Infinity and let it unmodified if it's the case.

```
public class Hero implements Actor{

    //initialize these fields differently in each Actor implementation
    private Life life;
    private Model model;

    public void init() {
    // different initialization values here
    }
}

public class Cannon implements Actor{

    //initialize these fields differently in each Actor implementation
    private Life life;
    private Model model;

    public void init() {
    // different initialization values here
    }
}
```